# Kindle fire, microphone

Tags: android, kindle

I am an android developer. I plan to implement my existing android application (which does voice to text) on Amazon Kindle Fire. I created a test device as per the amazon kindle help as i don't have kindle fire with me. I have a doubt that what happens if i click on microphone icon on my app with out connecting external mic (kindle does not have built-in mic as per specification). Does it lead to a crash? Do kindle handle this?

Comment: Please buy a Kindle Fire before attempting to develop a hardware-dependent application for the Kindle Fire.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with CommonsWare above that you really need to own the hardware to develop an app properly for that platform.

To assist a bit with other that are looking into this issue, it has been reported (and I have verified) that you can use cellphone headsets with the Fire and some apps to recognize the headset mic.

Source: http://www.the-digital-reader.com/2011/11/27/how-to-add-a-microphone-to-the-kindle-fire/

Are you developing natively or using a crossplatform IDE like Titanium or PhoneGap?

Comment: @ John Mark Mitchell No... I was using the Native SDK, I tried it with my 7" tab